# In metric space, f:homeomorphism. About preimage of an open ball

Tags: general-topology

In metric space, let f be a homeomorphism.

Is the preimage of an open ball still open ball?

I know that the preimage of an open set is open. So I can take open neighborhood of a point. But in my situation, I can only consider open ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For instance $f(x,y) = (x,y/2)$ is a homeomorphism of the plane, but preimages of balls are not balls.